# Displaying a non-transparent auto closing overlay with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I want to show a non-transparent full-screen overlay that closes after x seconds in VueJs. I stumbled upon v-overlay.

```
<VOverlay v-model="isOverlayVisible" v-bind:closeOnContentClick="false">
  <span>foo</span>
</VOverlay>
```

Current problems-

1. The overlay has a default transparency of 32% and even if I set
   opacity in the style tag to 1 it's still semi transparent
2. Though I set closeOnContentClick to false, it still closes when I click the content
3. I want the overlay to close after x seconds. I thought `closeDelay` will do that, but that doesn't work. I could implement a timer to set isOverlayVisible back to false, but I thought maybe there's already something implemented like in the snack bar component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query 1-** Apply opacity 1 to the class selector `.v-overlay__scrim`.

**Query 2-** `closeOnContentClick` is applicable only on the content not on the screen. If you will click on content, the overlay will not close but if you will click anywhere else on the screen, it will close. For your use-case, you should use the `persistent` prop, it will keep the overlay open unless you close it manually.

**Query 3-**  Use `settimeout` to close the overlay after x seconds like [this example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/overlays/#loader).

Here is a working demo-

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  data: () => ({
    overlay: false,
  }),
  watch: {
    overlay (val) {
      val && setTimeout(() => {
        this.overlay = false
      }, 5000)
    },
  },
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.v-overlay__scrim {
 opacity: 1 !important;
 background: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-btn @click="overlay = !overlay">Show Overlay</v-btn>
    <v-overlay v-model="overlay" persistent>
      <span>This overlay will not close on click but auto close after 5 seconds.</span>
    </v-overlay>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. 

2 and 3 worked like a charm.
1: I need to set different colors to every overlay, so this didn't work in my case. But I ended up with setting the opacity of .v-overlay__scrim to 0 and setting the backgroud of the v-overlay to my desired color.